# PyQGIS error: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'xMinimum'

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have the following code:

```
def moveFiles(self):
    mask = self.getBoundingBox() #BoundingBox of polygon layer
    inputDir = self.dlg.input_folder.text() #directory of xyz files - "Users/denni/Desktop/xyz_data"
    outDir = self.dlg.output_folder.text()  #output directory - "C:/Users/denni/Desktop/output/"
    os.chdir(inputDir)
    crs = "EPSG:25832"

    for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
        uri = "file:///" + inputDir +"/"+ file + "?type=csv&delimiter=%s&crs=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", crs, "field_1", "field_2")
        name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
        lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "delimitedtext")
        outputPath = outDir + file

        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMinimum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMinimum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMaximum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMinimum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMaximum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMaximum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMinimum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMaximum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

and the following error message:

> 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'xMinimum'

In the first line, I get the `polygon.boundingBoxOfSelected()` of a polygon. `boundingBoxOfSelected()` returns a `QgsRectangle` according to the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.boundingBoxOfSelected) . And according to this [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsRectangle.html?highlight=qgsrectangle#qgis.core.QgsRectangle.xMinimum), I should be able to access the functions `xMinimum()` and `xMaximum()`.

Thus, I don't understand the error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rectangle indeed has xMinimum, but you compare with a layer object.

Comment: yes you are right! **lyr.xMinimum()** doesn't work becaue lyr is not a QgsRectangle. 
2nd Problem was that I needed to use **elif** instead of **if**

If you post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is about `lyr.xMinimum()`, not `mask.xMinimum`. `QgsVectorLayer` has not `xMinimum` method as the error states. But `extent` method of `QgsVectorLayer` object gives you a `QgsRectangle` object. Then you can use `xMinimum` method using that object.

Use like this

```
extent = lyr.extent()
if mask.xMinimum() <= extent.xMinimum() <= mask.xMaximum() ....
```